# Delta Method around zero is a N(0, 0)

Tags: econometrics, convergence, asymptotics, estimators, delta-method

I have this problem: $\sqrt N \hat{\theta} \sim N(0, V)$ where $E(\hat{\theta}) = \theta_{0} = 0$. I must find the asymthotic distribution of $\frac{N}{V}\hat{\theta}^{2}$ but if I use the Delta Method I get that $\frac{N}{V}\hat{\theta}^{2} \sim N(\frac{N}{V}\theta_{0}^{2}, \frac{4\theta_{0}^{2}}{V}) = N(0, 0)$.

Any way to evade $N(0,0)$?

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method read second order delta method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The delta method is not needed here.  The square of a standard normal random variable is a [chi-squared random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution) with one degree-of-freedom.